# extending permutation algorithm (including duplicates)

Tags: algorithm, combinations, permutation

I m looking for an algorithm that give all possible combinations of letters

Let me explain better. If i have

```
base-letters = ["a","b","c"];
depth = 2; //max chars allowed
```

then the expected result would be these 12 elements (*3^1 + 3^2 = 12*):

```
["a", "b", "c", "aa","ab","ac","ba","bb","bc","ca", "cb", "cc"]
```

If i had a depth value = 3, i would expect (3^1) + (3^2) + (3^3) = 39 elements

```
["a", "b", ... , "aa", "ab", ... , "aaa", "aab", ..., "aba", ...]
```

Now, if i understood correctly permutation algorithm is similar, but doesn't consider **duplicated** letters (like "aa","bb","aab", "aba"), and the **variable depth** value (it could be different then base-letters length).

Comment: This can b done using recursion.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a recursive function F(s) which takes a string s of length less than or equal to your maximum length, and start by calling F(s) with s equal to the empty string. The function F computes the length of the string and if it is equal to the maximum length, it prints the string s and returns. If the length of the string is less than the maximum, then F(s) prints out the string s and then iterates over all possible letters in the alphabet and for each letter, it adds the letter to the end of string s to produce a string s' of length one more, and then calls F(s'). This has very low memory usage and is essentially the fastest method possible, at least in asymptotic terms.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, use [itertools's permutations function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) (a code recipe is included if you need to translate the code to your native language)

```
>>> import itertools
>>> base_elements = ['a', 'b', 'cow']
>>> max_depth = 2
>>> result = [''.join(element) for element in itertools.chain.from_iterable([itertools.permutations(base_elements, depth) for depth in range(1, max_depth+1)])]
>>> print(result)
['a', 'b', 'cow', 'ab', 'acow', 'ba', 'bcow', 'cowa', 'cowb']
```

If you want only unique values, then rather than concatenating the each output element into a string, create a set. This removes duplicates. Then remove duplicates from the final set.

```
>>> result = frozenset([frozenset(element)
                        for element in itertools.chain.from_iterable(
                          [itertools.permutations(base_elements, depth)
                           for depth in range(1, max_depth+1)]
                        )])
```

Or more cleanly,

```
def permutations(base_elements, max_depth):
    result = set()
    for depth in range(1, max_depth+1):
        for element in itertools.permutations(base_elements, depth):
            result.add(frozenset(element))
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems this code will give you what you need:

```
def all_strs(iterable, depth):
    results = []
    if depth==1:
        for item in iterable:
            results.append(str(item))
        return results
    for item in iterable:
        for s in all_strs(iterable, depth-1):
            results.append(str(item) + s)
    return results

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print all_strs('abc', 2)
    print all_strs([1, 2, 3], 3)

    s = 'abc'
    results = []
    for i in range(len(s)):
        results += print all_strs(s, i+1)
    print results
```

the output is:
['aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ba', 'bb', 'bc', 'ca', 'cb', 'cc']

['111', '112', '113', '121', '122', '123', '131', '132', '133', '211', '212', '213', '221', '222', '223', '231', '232', '233', '311', '312', '313', '321', '322', '323', '331', '332', '333']

['a', 'b', 'c', 'aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ba', 'bb', 'bc', 'ca', 'cb', 'cc', 'aaa', 'aab', 'aac', 'aba', 'abb', 'abc', 'aca', 'acb', 'acc', 'baa', 'bab', 'bac', 'bba', 'bbb', 'bbc', 'bca', 'bcb', 'bcc', 'caa', 'cab', 'cac', 'cba', 'cbb', 'cbc', 'cca', 'ccb', 'ccc']